# Skip last 2 words in a sentence in java

Tags: java, string, split, substring

In my java program,

How to skip last two words in sentence?

My input string is: `Hi there. My name is Kalp. This is my lucky day. I like coding so much. This is it.`

Expected output is: `Hi there. name My is Kalp. my is This lucky day. coding like I so much. This is it.`

Anyone Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
static String reverseExceptLast2Words(String input) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (String senence : input.split("\\.\\s*")) {
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList(senence.split("\\s+"));
        Collections.reverse(words.subList(0, Math.max(0, words.size() - 2)));
        output.append(String.join(" ", words)).append(". ");
    }
    return output.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Hi there. My name is Kalp. This is my lucky day. I like coding so much. This is it.";
    String output = reverseExceptLast2Words(input);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

output:

```
Hi there. name My is Kalp. my is This lucky day. coding like I so much. This is it.
```